# Is it possible to redirect packets to a different network in python?

Tags: python, redirect, networking, packet

Is it somehow possible to use something like a packet sniffer to send select packets over an alternate network? For example if I browse something it should go over network A, and if I do anything else needing an internet connection it should go over network B (Provided the computer is connected to both).

Is there any way to implement this in Python, and if not what other language may this be possible in?

Apologies if this question is unrealistic, I am actually relatively new to coding.

Comment: Generally yes, it's called routing. Practically no. Most modern web connections use encryption on the transport layer. So without a MITM attack, it is impossible to inspect the packages to determine the protocol they are using.

Comment: I don't understand what you really want to do - you have to better describe, and maybe shows some code. Normally `routers` decide which network is used to send data. If one network is disconnected than they may try to send it using other network.

Comment: @furas basically, I want to split my network traffic across two connections or maybe even more. How should I go about doing this?